# Issues including C++ files with Objective C on iOS

Tags: objective-c, xcode, objective-c++

I'm trying to include several different items from AudioCore, in particular, AQRecorder.  This does, however, have dependencies on c++ code.  Normally this is not an issue as I just rename my view controller to have the extension .mm and everything is great.  But in this case, my dependency on AQRecorder.h indirectly goes to my main.m which is causing me great pain.

I've tried several different things including the following:

1) Changing all .m and .cpp files -> .mm files

Everything compiles perfectly, however, it can't deploy to my iOS device or simulator as I get this error when deploying to the device:

> "Choose a destination with a supported architecture in order to run on
>   this device."

I'm using XCode 4.6 and my valid architectures are armv7 & armv7s (I've played with these but with no luck).

2) Tried using opaque pointers such as that in this guide:

http://philjordan.eu/article/mixing-objective-c-c++-and-objective-c++

I still run into the same issue where it won't compile.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AQWrappedRecorder", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in RTPPacketSender.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My dependencies are as follows:

AQRecorder.h -> RTPPacketSender.h -> ActiveConversationViewController.h -> ConversationViewController.h -> AppDelegate.h -> main.m

Can anybody else recommend anything to try.  I've quite literally spent all day debugging this issue with no luck.

Vince

Comment: Can you post the code excerpt that is causing you problems? (I'm the author of the linked article - there's actually a newer one on the site that might be helpful) If you're targeting only non-fragile ABIs (iOS and/or 64-bit OSX) you might want to place your C++-typed instance variables in a class extension instead of the header.

Comment: I ended up actually just porting everything to objective c to end my frustrations.